# Exception HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when Opening Rights Management File using Application.Open()

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in, drm

I have a Excel Add-in for Office 2013 developed using VSTO and a RMS file protected by Azure Rights Management System. When I open RMS file using add-in such as follows:

```
Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
```

I get exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in XXXXX.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Exception from **HRESULT: 0x800A03EC**

Does anyone have idea why I am getting this exception? I looked for information regarding this error code but couldn't find one relevant to my situation.

Comment: What file path exactly is passed to the Open method?

Comment: Filepath is exactly like this except username is masked : C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Test.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my own question. When open a RMS file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(), you must be signed in to Excel w/ a user who has permission to open that file. FYI, this is true to PowerPoint. PowerPoint throws HRESULT E_FAIL. Word is an exception. HOWEVER, Word is an exception. Word prompt you for credential if you are not signed in, after providing a valid credential, it opens fine. I have no idea why these application behave differently.